# Looking to include subdirectories as an item to delete

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This command is pretty basic as I'm just learning, but I'm trying to include subdirectories along with files to be deleted after 14 days. Thanks for any help and guidance.

```
forfiles /p "C:\testFolder" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -14
```

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Because `ForFiles` has an `@IsDir` option it shouldn't restrict itself to files. On that basis does it include the directories if you change **`*.*`** to **`*`**?

Comment: You can't remove directories with the `DEL` command. Using the `DEL` command on a directory just removes files from the directory.  If you want to remove a directory then you need to use the `RD` command.