# Using batch processing to delete files and folders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

I've been working with this script to help achieve my goal, which is deleting files and folders, but I'm a little confused as to how I can add a time length to it. I would like to delete files and folders after 2 weeks, any suggestions?

```
set folder="C:\test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

I've built off this post ([Batch file. Delete all files and folders in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/batch-file-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)) but am unable to comment as my reputation doesn't allow it. Thanks again

Comment: What was wrong with you updating your previous [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46183829/6738015). You have had two days additional time to learn how the forum works, further your knowledge and provide a better quality pertinent question. Adding code that is copied from a non similar question and which does not consider file dates or ages is really not good enough.

Comment: Or your other same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221946/looking-to-include-subdirectories-as-an-item-to-delete

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answer provided by kranz, my humble suggestion is to add a fail safe in second command otherwise in case `cd` command fails, `rmdir` and `del` will wreak havoc in your current directory.

Following code will exit the script in case `%folder%` is not a valid path.

```
cd /d %folder% || exit /B 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file and add to Task Scheduler to be executed every 2 weeks

Check this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/) for more details